# Which version of Microsoft Tape Format is supported by which MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, backup

When you create a backup with Microsoft Sql Server, the resulting file is in [Microsoft Tape Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Tape_Format).
Different versions of SQL Server apparently use different version of this format.

Which version of SQL server is required to **restore** a given file with a specific format version?

Can I somehow influence the version SQL server uses when **creating** a backup?

---

**Background:** 
I am currently trying to restore a database backup created with an unknown version of SQL server, probably 2012. I have SQL Server Express 2008 R2. When executing the command

```
RESTORE VERIFYONLY FROM DISK='C:\myfile.bak'
```

I get the error

```
The media family on device 'C:\myfile.bak' was created 
using Microsoft Tape Format version 1.8. 
SQL Server supports version 1.0.
```

I guess this is simply a case of being unable to restore a database with an older version of SQL server, and there is nothing to be done about that besides upgrading. However I found no information about which MS tape format version corresponds to which sql server, and the error message is not very enlightening.

Therefore, in order to understand such error messages, I am interested in some general information about this format, in particular the exact correspondences between tape format version numbers to SQL Server version numbers.

---

Update:

It seems this is not simply a problem with the wrong version of SQL Server.

Restoring on SQL Server 2012 Express failed with the same error.

When executing a `RESTORE HEADERONLY` the resulting headers where

```
BackupName: *** INCOMPLETE ***
Position: 1
Every other column: NULL
```

I am currently in the process of acquiring another copy of the file.

Comment: The backup is corrupted. You would need a new backup inorder to restore it.

Comment: @Kin That is a possibility I had not considered. I thought a corrupt file would result in some sort of failed checksum and a corresponding error message. Can a backup file randomly corrupt in such a way that it looks like a valid file with a different format version?

Comment: How did you get the backup file ? Through ftp ? Is it possible to restore on the same server that you took backup ?

Comment: I got the file trough ftp and I am in the process of requesting another copy sent to me. Communication in this case is difficult however, and I am not confident in my ability to explain to them how to restore a backup without overwriting the production database. (Just as I am not confident that the sql server version reported to me is the correct one)

Comment: Have you tried running `RESTORE HEADERONLY` on the backup? If this succeeds, it will give you the server version where the backup was taken. If it doesn't, or it comes back with a weird result, then try the restore on a higher version.

Comment: @HugoRune I ran into the same issue when we get backups from clients through ftp. Always use **binary mode** in ftp.For `I am not confident in my ability to explain to them how to restore a backup without overwriting the production database.`, you can just ask to restore the backup as a different database e.g. `database_temp`. Also as Jon Seigel pointed out that `RESTORE HEADERONLY` will give you the server version. You can always restore a lower version to a higher version, but the other way is not possible. Ask the client to get you the `select @@version`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was indeed a corrupted backup, as Kin correctly deduced. Most likely the corruption was introduced during an ftp transfer.

So, when you get the error "*The media family on device 'C:\myfile.bak' was created using Microsoft Tape Format version 1.8. SQL Server supports version 1.0.*" or the error "*Specified cast is not valid. (SqlManagerUI)*" when using the SQL Management studio Gui to restore a backup, you most likely have a corrupted backup file.

In my case, zipping the file before ftp transfer solved the problem.

You would *think* that backup files always contain a checksum, and if the file was later modified that sql server would report this incorrect checksum, but you would be *wrong*.